# Bullet Physic - Ringtoss game: goal

Tags: bulletphysics

Me and my freind are trying to create a game engine to make a ringtoss simulator using bullet physic on VS C++. Everything goes quite well until we need some way to determite the score (detect if the ring was put inside the pole). For the ring I use btCompoundShape with 36 little Shpere, here is the code:

```
btRigidBody* SceneManager::AddRing(float rad, float thick, float x, float y, float z, float mass)
{
    btTransform t;
    btCompoundShape *comShape = new btCompoundShape;
    btSphereShape* sphere = new btSphereShape(thick / 2.0);
    //sphere->setUserIndex(8);
    float masses[36];

    for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
    {
        t.setIdentity();
        t.setOrigin(btVector3((rad - thick / 2.0)*sin(3.14159265359 / 180.0 * 10 * i), 0, (rad - thick / 2.0)*cos(3.14159265359 / 180.0 * 10 * i)));
        comShape->addChildShape(t, sphere);
        //comShape->addChildShape(t, box);
        masses[i] = mass / 36;
    }

    btVector3 inertia(0, 0, 0);
    t.setIdentity();
    comShape->calculatePrincipalAxisTransform(masses, t, inertia);
    t.setIdentity();
    t.setOrigin(btVector3(x, y, z));

    btMotionState* motion = new btDefaultMotionState(t);
    btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo info(mass, motion, comShape, inertia);  
    btRigidBody* body = new btRigidBody(info);   


    sceneWorld->addRigidBody(body); 
    vRigidBody.push_back(body);

    return body;
}
```

Anyhow, I have try three diffrent way to check the goal:

- I use callBackFunc and body->setUserIndex(int i), however for this method, the ring only need to touch the pole to count as goal.
- I check the position of the center of the ring to the pole, this way work but sometime when the ring get to close to the pole or stand sideway to it, it also count.
- I check 4 point on the ring like the 4 direction on the compase relative to the position of the pole, this suffer the same result as above.

I am new to bullet Physic, if any adept out there who could help I would really appreciate it.